# Matlab cell to matrix vectorization

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, vectorization, data-analysis

I have a cell with 3 synchronized signals in each column. I want to extract specific segments into my seg cell. How do I get rid of the loop here?

```
data = cell(1, 3);
data{1,1} = [ones(30, 1)];
data{1,2} = [1:30]';
data{1,3} = 2*[1:30]';
ind1 = [1; 11; 17];
ind2 = [10; 16; 30];

for i = 1:3
    seg{i, 1} = [data{:,1}(ind1(i):ind2(i)) data{:,2}(ind1(i):ind2(i)) data{:,3}(ind1(i):ind2(i))];   
end
```

Comment: What's the end goal? Why do you want to get rid of the loop? If it's pure performance then the better option would be to avoid cells all together and use a matrix...

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
data = cell(1, 3);
data{1,1} = ones(30, 1);
data{1,2} = (1:30)';
data{1,3} = 2*(1:30)';

D = cell2mat(data);
Cel = mat2cell(D,[10 6 14],3);
```

Comment: Not quite, I gave an arbitrary example, but pretend the ind1 (start index of segment) and ind2 (end index) are generated at runtime. I essentially have my signals and I want to extract the segments specified by ind1(i) : ind2(i).

Comment: Even if `ind1` and `ind2` are generated at runtime, you can do `mat2cell(D,ind2-ind1+1,3)` and get the same result.